# SpringMVC testing post method with params

Tags: java, spring-mvc-test

I'm writing test for SpringMvc app, and i've run into some issue.

here is my controller method for test:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "submit", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "delete")
public String delete(@ModelAttribute("inputBean") InputBean inputBean) {
    Book book = (Book) itemServiceController.getItemFindByIdService().findById(inputBean.getId());
    Author author = getAuthorOfBook(book);
    author.getBookList().remove(book);
    authorServiceController.getAuthorCreateService().create(authorServiceController.getAuthorUpdateService().update(author));
    itemServiceController.getItemDeleteService().delete(inputBean.getId());
    return "redirect:index.html";
}
```

here is my mockMvc:

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/submit?delete")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .param("id", "1")
            .sessionAttr("inputBean", new InputBean())
            )
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(view().name("indexLib"))
    .andExpect(model().attribute("inputBean", hasProperty("id", is(1))));
```

This returns status http status 400.

Controller method is made for 1 of 4 form submit buttons. How to fix this?

Comment: What's the actual exception you get?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, the proper url should be

```
"/submit?id=102&delete="
```